# Replace the values in a column with the mathematical product involving values in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database which has a table for sales data. Two of the columns in this table are  of the type "Money, null". Due to the incorrect usage of the software this database relies on, value was assigned to column B which should have been assigned to column A.

Column B has only 0.0000 or positive numerical data which is a money value in cents. Column A has some positive, some negative, and some 0.0000 numerical data which is money value in dollars. The data in column A is accurate and should remain. The values in column B should be first divided by 100 (to convert to dollars), made a negative value, and added to the data in column A (if applicable).

The data in column B can then be removed, the values there should all end up as 0.0000.

Example starting data:

```
Column_A        Column_B
0.0000          2500.0000
40.0000         1000.0000
-25.0000        0.0000
-32.0000        1500.0000
0.0000          0.0000
```

Column_B values are converted to:
-25.0000
-10.0000
0.0000
-15.0000
0.0000

and added to their respective Column_A values. The data in column B will never start as a negative.

Example ending data:

```
Column_A        Column_B
-25.0000        0.0000
30.0000         0.0000
-25.0000        0.0000
-47.0000        0.0000
0.0000          0.0000
```

My knowledge of SQL is fairly limited, and I can carry out simple queries, but I've had no experience carrying out mathematical operations such as this, and a search on google and stack exchange hasn't yielded any similar queries that I might be able to repurpose. If anyone could help to point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do a select to ensure nothing falls through (divide by zero errors etc) like so:

```
select 

    Column_A
    , Column_B
    , Column_A+(Column_B/100)*-1.0  

from your_table
```

If everything checks out proceed by doing the math first, update `column_A` and then update `column_B`.

So your SQL statement will be something like this:

```
update your_table
  set Column_A = Column_A+(Column_B/100)*-1.0
  , Column_B = 0.00
```

Comment: This is fantastic, I've tested this on my own testing database with all possible starting data values, and I seem to have gotten the results I'm after. I'll go ahead and carry this out on the working DB shortly. This definitely helped me to understand the math component of what I'd been trying to do. Thanks a lot Harry!

Answer (score 0):

If your apps are still running with the same error, and you need to retrieve the column with the desired information, try this :)

(it will create a new column named Column_C with your desired result)

```
SELECT *, (([Column_B] * -0.01) + [Column_A]) AS Column_C FROM myTable
```

Otherwise, if you need to change the columns values in the table, Harry's Answer is what you need